Proving that sine is irrational at rational arguments with infinite fractions
In his proof of irrationality of $\pi$, Lambert uses the following continued fraction for tangent:
$$\tan x=\cfrac{x}{1-
\cfrac{x^2}{3-\cfrac{x^2}{5-\cfrac{x^2}{7-\cdots}}}}$$
He notes that for any fixed $x \in \mathbb{Q}$/{$0$}, the remainders of this fraction will at some point be less than one. If the fraction is itself rational, this would lead to an infinite sequence of decreasing positive integers which is impossible. For more details see this question.
Euler's continued fraction formula allows us to write a similar expression for the sine function:
$$\sin x=\cfrac{x}{1+
\cfrac{x^2}{6-x^2+\cfrac{6x^2}{20-x^2+\cfrac{20x^2}{42-x^2+\cdots}}}}$$
But that reasoning fails to apply because the remainders do not fall below one. Taking $x=\frac{p}{q}$ and then removing denominators gives a remainder of the form:
$$\cfrac{k(k+1)p^2q^2}{(k+2)(k+3)q^2-p^2+\cdots} \longrightarrow p^2$$
Ivan Niven in his book on irrational numbers gives a proof of irrationality of cosine at nonzero rational values via a certain integral identity. No continued fractions there.
If it works for tangent, why doesn't it work for sine? And if this method is so narrowly applicable, why did Lambert decide to pursue it, and why did it work, what makes tangent so special?

The Lindemann Weierstraß theorem is complicated , but allows to say even more about the functions sin,cos,tan

I am only aware of a Lambert-proof where it is refuted that $\pi^2$ is rational. This also disproofs that $\pi$ is rational. For the continued fraction argument , we first have to show that continued fractions like those are irrational at all which is only trivial in the case of a simple continued fraction.
